# Delphi IDE shortcut for splitting a long string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2. I have a really long string (580 characters) pasted into the IDE. I want to split the string so that it stays within the right margins and has the proper closing tick mark and plus sign. Is there a keyboard shortcut that will do that?

The shift + Enter shortcut allows me to do if I am typing the string but it doesn't split a string that is already on the screen.

Comment: Go to the end of your string, removee the terminating quote, press shift enter

Comment: @David No, that doesn't split the string at the right margin displayed in the IDE. At least not for me with my default settings on XE7. Shift+Enter closes the end of the string, adds a plus, a line break, and opens a new string to continue typing. Doesn't help when you already have a long string pasted. Also, OP already addressed their trials with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi XE2 has the ability to record Macros and play them back in your source editor. The controls are in the bottom-left, play, record, and stop.

[image]

- If not already, move your string down to the next line (as in my screenshot)
- Start with your cursor at the beginning of the string, after the `'`
- Press the `Record Macro` button (Red circle)
- Press the `Right` keyboard arrow key up to 2 chars before desired width
- Type `'` to terminate the string
- Type `+` to continue on the next line
- Press `Enter` to insert a line break
- Type `'` to begin a new string
- By now you should be 1 position directly underneath where you started
- Press the `Stop Recording Macro` button (Green square)
- Press the `Playback Macro` button (Green triangle)
- Continue pressing play until all is complete

Comment: I was about to post the exact same answer!  The lack of this sort of macro recording/playback is the single biggest pain point for me when working in the current versions of Visual Studio (because who needs macros when you have refactoring and formatting tools?).  To answer my own question:  Code formatting/refactorings are great, except when they fail to cover simple, mechanically repetitive editing steps like this.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> only works like you want when the cursor is at the *end* of a line with an unclosed string literal. There is no shortcut to split a literal (with quotes and spacing) when the cursor is at the *beginning* or *middle* of it.  You will have to find a third-party editor add-on that formats long string literals the way you want.

Comment: Why go to the bother of a 3rd party editor when the Delphi editor has all the tools you need ? (see Jerry's answer - macros are a perfect fit for the sort of mechanical/repetitive formatting task involved in this and similar cases).

Answer (score -2):

You can press "CTRL+D"....  and configure it in Tools->Options->Formatter

Comment: The code formatter in XE2 does not have options to cover this particular situation. Although it has options to govern line breaks, that only applies to statements and functions, it does not insert line breaks inside of long string literals.